# Is it possible to have multiple tags in xpath, python

Tags: python, xpath

I want to extract text from either an a tag or a p tag and wondering whether I can do them both in the same `XPATH`.

XPATH would look like this:

```
'//*[contains(@id, "profile")]/div/div/div/div/a|h4/a'
```

where '|' means a tag or h4 tag

Answer (score 1):

Use `self` axis

```
//*[contains(@id, "profile")]/div/div/div/div/*[self::a or self::h4]/a
```

And if you want `.../div/a` or `.../div/h4/a`, use union of two Xpath

```
//*[contains(@id, "profile")]/div/div/div/div/a | //*[contains(@id, "profile")]/div/div/div/div/a
```